# Why are my MVC 4 Authorize checks throwing an exception?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server Express 2012.  I created an MVC 4 Web Application using the "Internet Application" template.

I wanted to use an existing database on my instance of SQL Server 2012 Express (as opposed to the template's MDF).  I have modified my web.config to point to my local SQL express instance instead and have deleted the template-generated MDF.  My Web.Config has:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
    connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Administration;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The stock membership code has a call to initialize the DB:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Once the application fires up, the tables get created in the Administration database as I would expect.  I can create users and they are populated in Administration.  I can populate the roles table and add roles to a user's profile through code and verify that it took.  e.g.:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser("kristian"); // = string[] { "Administrator" }
```

But if I try and use role-based authorization like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
```

I get the following exception:

```
Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.
```

It gives a long nasty stack trace that makes me think it's still trying to create an MDF file:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to a failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295167
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +69
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +30
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +317
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +889
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5309659
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5311874
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +76

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +131
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +89
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.Install(String database, String dbFileName, String connectionString) +27
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +386

The line at the bottom of this bundle of joy makes me think it's related to the now-deleted MDF ('System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile').  Am I correct in this?  Or is the authorization implemented by the template just incomplete?

If someone else has dealt with this or knows why my attribute usage is failing I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: did you try to search in entire solution (Ctrl Shift F) for "MDF" and replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. It appears to be related to not initializing SimpleMembership properly. Try making sure that `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` is used or directly call `Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);`